# How to push my customize Push notification for Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, push-notification

I am working on question and answer website and wonder to create push notification for this site but is it possible that user subscribes for notification on site and then I could send notification later to chrome whenever its question is answer and user are on another tab of chrome or may be closed the chrome.

Maybe it feels bit foolish but just want to clear my concept about Chrome notification.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to explain the working of push notification to you. We will use your case study.

User visits your website, he sees the pop-up/dialog box to subscribe to push notification. He clicks on Allow. After clicking on Allow, he will be subscribed to push notifications from your website.

Now only thing the subscriber needs to do is, he need to keep the browser open. Even if the subscriber is not on your website, he will get push notification when you will send one from the tool/dashboard.

You can take a look at [PushCrew](https://pushcrew.com) - push notification tool. It will be easier for you to check how push notifications work.